# Necesito ocultar una columna del treeview en python para poder recorrer las columnas con un scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito ocultar la columna "Fecha" para poder recorrer las columnas con un scrollbar horizontal y poder agregar mas columnas para recorrerlas con un scrollbar horizontal, aquí les dejo una foto del treeview:[image: pantalla del treeview]

el pedazo de codigo:

```
studentView=ttk.Treeview(miFrame3, height=3,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6","7"))
studentView.grid(column=1,row=2)
studentView.heading('#0' , text="", anchor="w")
studentView.heading('#1' , text="up", anchor=CENTER)
studentView.heading('#2' , text="Nombre", anchor=CENTER)
studentView.heading('#3' , text="grupo", anchor=CENTER)
studentView.heading('#4' , text="carrera", anchor=CENTER,)
studentView.heading('#5' , text="hora etrada", anchor=CENTER)
studentView.heading('#6' , text="hora salida", anchor=CENTER)
studentView.heading('#7' , text="Fecha", anchor=CENTER)


studentView.column("#0",stretch=False, width=1)
studentView.column("#1",stretch=False, width=80)
studentView.column("#2",stretch=False, width=80)
studentView.column("#3",stretch=False, width=80)
studentView.column("#4",stretch=False, width=80)
studentView.column("#5",stretch=False, width=150)
studentView.column("#6",stretch=False, width=80)
studentView.column("#7",stretch=False, width=80)
```

el codigo para las scrollbar

esa es la vertical, que funciona correctamente

studentScrollBar=ttk.Scrollbar(miFrame3,orient="vertical",command=studentView.yview)
    studentView.configure(yscroll=studentScrollBar.set)
    studentScrollBar.grid(row=2,column=6,sticky="ns")

y la horizontal:

`studentScrollBar2=ttk.Scrollbar(miFrame3,orient="horizontal",command=studentView.xview)
    studentView.configure(xscroll=studentScrollBar2.set)
    studentScrollBar2.grid(column=1)`

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Si lo he entendido bien, creo que tu problema real es que no has configurado correctamente la barra horizontal, no necesitas ocultar la columna esto se hece automlaticamente si el tamaño excede el establecido, si todo está bien configurado. ¿Podrias agregar el código dónde creas y configuras las barras?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, ahorita actualizo el codigo

Comment: @FJSevilla ya actualice el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si mal no recuerdo, existe una funcion para mostrar solo algunas columnas.

```
self.tree["displaycolumns"]=("col1", "col2",...)
```

Donde:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.master)
```

Con esto serias capaz de hacer lo que buscas.

De todos modos, esto esta sacado de [otra respuesta algo mas antigua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290969/hiding-treeview-columns-in-tkinter) .

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias, dejame lo checo